# Effective to use const struct in C instead of defines for grouping configuration parameters?

Tags: c, struct, c-preprocessor, buildconfiguration

I am thinking of using a global constant struct to manage configuration of some sub-systems. This means that I would like to use something like:

```
const struct SystemConfig {
  .channels = 5,
  .mode = NORMAL_MODE,
} SYSTEM_CONFIG;
```

And later use it in my code like usual:

```
...
numberOfChannels = SYSTEM_CONFIG.channels;
mode = SYSTEM_CONFIG.mode;
...
```

I would like to use this approach to skip `#define`'s.

My question is if the compiler will realize this and replace the values with their respective values when it is compiled, considering everything is constant?

**EDIT:** Sorry for tagging both **C** and C++, it's fixed now and my question relates only to **C**. The compiler I use is GCC with a ARM Cortex-M4 target.

Comment: Give it a try and see!

Comment: The only way to find out is to look at the generated assembler code.

Comment: `...if the compiler will...` which compiler? And since it's tagged with both C and C++, which language?

Comment: Even if the compiler doesn't special case it, how much difference is it going to make to runtime of your code in practice?  The mechanism is quite neat and tidy; use it if you think the notational clarity is worthwhile (it might well be worth it).

Comment: @Niklas Norin Are you familiar with design patterns? Have you considered the Singletone pattern, it quit good fits to your needs, as you described them in your question

Answer (score 0):

I would use static const so your struct is not visible at link level. For example:

```
static const unsigned int channels = 5;
unsigned numberOfChannels = channels;
```

would definitely be optimised by a compiler. So I can't see why any modern compiler would be unable to optimise your example either.

If it was me I would find the compiler option to output the code it was laying down. It's an interesting exercise.